# Is Facebook Graph API considered a RESTful API?

Tags: facebook, rest

It seems that the old Facebook API was called the "REST API", while the new one is called the "Graph API". I wonder if the new Graph isn't a RESTful API as well? It seems like it conforms to the guiding principles of the [REST interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#Guiding_principles_of_the_interface), or am I wrong?

Thanks!

Joel

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is a REST API as well.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there have been 3 Facebook API's to date:

- Legacy REST
- FQL
- Graph API

The Legacy REST API is in the process of being deprecated, while the Graph API is the most current, so if you're unsure of which one to use, your best bet is to go with that one.

As you suggested, the Graph API, just like the Legacy REST API, is in fact a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#Guiding_principles_of_the_interface) API. It is my understanding that they now refer to their earlier REST API as the "Legacy REST" API in order to minimize confusion and distinguish it from the newer RESTful API (the Graph API).

Answer (score 3):

Well, it depends on [your definition of REST](http://www.bitnative.com/2012/08/26/how-restful-is-your-api/). But yes, usually the Graph API is also called RESTful.

Answer (score 1):

This post will help you:

http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/12/graphapi

I think Graph API is a new name for old API.